# Use of final keyword in case of objects

Tags: java, java-8

I know how to use final keywords.Suppose if make a class as final then it can not be inherited,if a method is final then it can not be overridden and if a variable is made final then the value can not be altered.But I am little bit confused in this case

```
    final TextField urlTextField = new TextField();
```

I think that if urlTextField is made final then you can not make again

urlTextField=new textField().But in the following example why it is made final

[Source](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/introduction-by-example-javafx-8-printing.html)

```
package org.carlfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.print.*;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demo to use JavaFX 8 Printer API.
 *
 * @author cdea
 */
public class PrintDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final TextField urlTextField = new TextField();
        final Button printButton = new Button("Print");
        final WebView webPage = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = webPage.getEngine();

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(urlTextField, printButton);
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(hbox);
        borderPane.setCenter(webPage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Print Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // print button pressed, page loaded
        final BooleanProperty printButtonClickedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        final BooleanProperty pageLoadedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        // when the a page is loaded and the button was pressed call the print() method.
        final BooleanProperty printActionProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        printActionProperty.bind(pageLoadedProperty.and(printButtonClickedProperty));

        // WebEngine updates flag when finished loading web page.
        webEngine.getLoadWorker()
                 .stateProperty()
                 .addListener( (ChangeListener) (obsValue, oldState, newState) -> {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        pageLoadedProperty.set(true);
                    }
                 });

        // When user enters a url and hits the enter key.
        urlTextField.setOnAction( aEvent ->  {
            pageLoadedProperty.set(false);
            printButtonClickedProperty.set(false);
            webEngine.load(urlTextField.getText());
        });

        // When the user clicks the print button the webview node is printed
        printButton.setOnAction( aEvent -> {
            printButtonClickedProperty.set(true);
        });

        // Once the print action hears a true go print the WebView node.
        printActionProperty.addListener( (ChangeListener) (obsValue, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState) {
                print(webPage);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /** Scales the node based on the standard letter, portrait paper to be printed.
     * @param node The scene node to be printed.
     */
    public void print(final Node node) {
        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.NA_LETTER, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
        double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
        double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
        node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (job != null) {
            boolean success = job.printPage(node);
            if (success) {
                job.endJob();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: By using `final` one declares that this variable cannot be changed (by re-assigning). What's the problem ?

Comment: The use of `final` in this case is to allow the nested classes/closures access the objects (ie, the event handlers in the `start` method)

Comment: @MadProgrammer not class - closure (which is probably translated to an inner anonymous class) ;)

Comment: @alfasin Not an FX developer - sorry, naughty me :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer it has nothing to do with FX - I think that Java 8 started supporting closures, so we'll all know what it is really soon :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Inner classes?here there no inner classes.Soory could not understand you properly

Comment: @alfasin Yeah, something else I have to learn :P (lol)

Comment: @javaBeginner Have a read of the conversion between myself and alfasin - *"not class - closure (which is probably translated to an inner anonymous class)"*

Comment: @MadProgrammer you said "which is probably translated to an inner anonymous class". Can you be a bit clearer in this case

Comment: @javaBeginner As I said, I'm not a FX developer, nor do I have access to Java 8 yet, so I'm using the closets concept I have at hand...

Comment: @alfasin you said"By using final one declares that this variable cannot be changed (by re-assigning). What's the problem ?" Here in this example,the developer has not attempted to reassign or change or etc.Even though if its not final then works well.

Comment: @javaBeginner I started responding but then it became too long... see my answer below - hope it makes things more  clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 7, when you're in an anonymous class and you're trying to use/approach a variable of the wrapping class - that variable should be declared `final` or the compiler will complain. Same thing applies to Lambda expressions (supported from Java 8). Try removing the `final` from the declaration and you'll get a compiler error on the 4th line:

```
    urlTextField.setOnAction( aEvent ->  {
        pageLoadedProperty.set(false);
        printButtonClickedProperty.set(false);
        webEngine.load(urlTextField.getText()); // <-- compile error 
    });
```

From the [*documentation*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) :

> An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing
>   scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.

[*Lambda expressions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach5) and anonymous classes share similar properties (a lambda expression can be defined as a combination of two things: a code and a scope). In addition to that, Lambda expressions, like inner classes, can use only `final` (or "effectively final") variables that were declared outside the lambda. The following is an example from the *[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)*:

```
        // The following statement causes the compiler to generate
        // the error "local variables referenced from a lambda expression
        // must be final or effectively final" in statement A:
        //
        // x = 99;

        Block<Integer> myBlock = (y) -> 
        {
            System.out.println("x = " + x); // Statement A
            System.out.println("y = " + y);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("LambdaScopeTest.this.x = " +
                LambdaScopeTest.this.x);
        };
```

Comment: In the given code what is the inner class neither i am creating any anonymous class.

Comment: The code that starts `aEvent ->  {...` is creating a closure. It's mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: If I remember correctly (and they didn't change it) then accessing a variable in a closure *also* works when the variables is "effectively final" (i.e. you need not *write* the `final`, but you have to follow most of its rules).

Comment: @JoachimSauer not according to the last link in my answer ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if that link is entirely up-to-date. It talks about two different closure specifications and I'm pretty sure the decision is done and there's only one relevant now. So other things might have changed. Unfortunately I am not able to find my source of the "effectively final" clause at the moment, I'll continue searching.

Comment: Ha! I found the most unlikely source: [The Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class): "a local class can access local variables [..] that are final or effectively final." It's also mentioned in the [State of the Lambda (by Brian Götz)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html)

Comment: @alfasin this is off the topic,can you give some links or book names for learning java fx.I mean for javafx beginners

Comment: @JoachimSauer item #7 - I see: `in inner classes (captured variables) is quite restrictive in Java SE 7: an error occurs if the captured variable is not declared final. We relax this restriction` awesome! thanks for the links!

Comment: This answer is wrong considering the tags used for the question.

Comment: @alfasin in your new example at the bottom of your answer you seem to imply that `x` needs to be final which is not the case (the argument of the method in the link you provide is not final) but it must be effectively final and can't be reassigned. I suggest you experiment with Java 8 to get a better understanding of how all that works.

Comment: @assylias right, it has to be either final or effectively final, which means that it's not final but still we can't change it inside the body of the lambda

Answer (score 7):

Until Java 7 you need to declare a local variable final to access it from an inner class.

From Java 8 on this is not required any longer: [the variable only need to be effectively final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing) (i.e. not changed). That change was made to be consistent with the lambda syntax.

So technically you don't need the final keyword here if you are using Java FX 8.

Comment: All the things that you wrote here - were already mentioned above in the answers+comments.

Comment: @assylias Thanks for answering,good point to learn so +1.Well I am little bit consfused.you said "Until Java 7 you need to declare a local variable final to access it from an inner class".here in my code which is the inner class.

Comment: @javaBeginner I'm having a Déjà vu :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908823/use-of-final-keyword-in-case-of-objects/#comment-27914384

Comment: @alfasin your answer states "Try removing the final from the declaration and you'll see that you'll get a compiler error on the 4th line" which is wrong with Java 8 (the tag used for the question) so I thought posting a more accurate answer would be useful.

Comment: @assylias I also wrote in two places (in my answer) that it's an error in Java 7, and then wrote that it doesn't apply to Java 8 (including links).

Comment: @alfasin Déjà vu :) what ?

Comment: @alfasin It wasn't there originally and your introduction paragraph is still wrong for Java 8.  For example you say "When you're in an inner class (and apparently **in a closure as well**) and you're trying to use/approach a variable of the outer class - that **variable should be declared final**" which is not the case. You don't need to declare a variable final to use it in a closure (or in an inner class). Bottom line is I think your answer is confusing.

Comment: @assylias again - you choose to look only at *part* of my answer: in the code that follows the cite (which you provided) there's a code comment that says that it applies to Java 7 only. In addition to that there's the last paragraph that explains it in more details. That said, especially for you, I'll add a "java 7" disclaimer at the beginning. Cause if you could make that mistake of understanding my answer the way you did - anyone can make it.

Comment: @alfasin there are no closures in Java 7 (which your text mentions and your code uses ) - the compiler would actually complain when it sees the `->`... I'll stop arguing here.

Comment: @assylias I think that Java 7 supports closures, check this out: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3719 and http://www.caglargonul.com/2013/04/05/playing-with-closures-in-java-7/

Comment: @assylias You're right - even though closure are supported, lambda expressions (`->`) are not supported in Java 7. Going to update my answer

Comment: @assylias all the discussion above about closures was not relevant :))) closures are defined using `=>` and lambda is defined with `->`. Very confusing... Good catch! thanks.

Comment: @alfasin not sure what you mean: `=>` is not valid in Java 8. And closures and lambdas are essentially the same thing. You can simulate closures before Java 8 with anonymous classes but with the restriction that you can't access the local variables around the class (unless they are final) and with the drawback that it is very verbose.

Comment: @assylias when I was talking about `=>` I was referring to this: http://www.javac.info/closures-v03.html and as for the example at the bottom of my answer, like I wrote, it's taken from the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @alfasin the first link is obsolete - this is not the syntax that has been adopted in Java 8. The `x` variable in the tutorial is **not** final.

Comment: @assylias right - it specifically says: final or effectively final